# Unble to add a class to Laravel form select

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

I'm using Laravel forms. This is my code in view.

```
<?php
      $options = $items->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
      $options[''] = "Choose...";
?>

{!! Form::select('item_id', $options, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
@error('item_id')
     <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

But unfortunately browser does not render css class,

```
<select name="item_id">
   ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter for the form is the selected option, so you need to pass the array with the classes as a fourth argument. For example:

```php
{!! Form::select('item_id', $options, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```